# Concavity of a function in terms of expected value

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, expected-value

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid standard gaussian random variable. Define the set $S$ as
$$
S = \{(z_1,...,z_n):z_i\geq 0,\sum_{i=1}^nz_i=1\}
$$
and the function $f:S\to[0,\infty)$ as
$$
f(z_1,...,z_n) = E\left[\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nz_iX_i^2}\right].
$$
Is it true that $f$ is concave? My approach was by calculating the Hessian:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_k\partial z_j} = -\frac{1}{4}E\left[\frac{(X_jX_k)^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nz_iX_i^2\right)^{3/2}}\right].
$$
I couldn't prove that this Hessian is non-positive definite.

Is there another way to prove that $f$ is concave? (Of course, if it is true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi(z,\omega) = \sqrt{\sum_k z_k X_k^2(\omega)}$ and note that for a fixed $\omega$ the function $\omega \mapsto \phi(z,\omega)$ is concave (composition of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and a linear function).
Hence $f(z) = E_\omega [ \phi(z,\omega) ] = \int_\Omega \phi(z,\omega) d \mu(\omega) $ is concave.